# Stacking multiple columns with different names into one giant dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have several data frames (with equal # columns but different names). I'm trying to create one data frame with rows stacked below each other. I don't care now about the column names (I can always rename them later). I saw different SO links but they don't address this problem completely.

Note I've 21 data frames and scalability is important. I was looking at 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590866/python-pandas-concat-dataframes-with-different-columns-ignoring-column-names)

[image]

How I get df:

```
df = []

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4])
    df.append(data)
```

Comment: Can you just show us some sample data

Comment: Are the columns/metrics in the same order regardless of their name?

Comment: @amrtw09: Yes, same order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrames are stored in some list `df_l`:

Rename the columns and concat:

```
df_l = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in df_l:
    df.columns = df_l[0].columns  # Just chose any DataFrame

pd.concat(df_l)  # Columns named with above DataFrame
                 # Index is preserved
```

Or construct a new DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.to_numpy() for df in df_l]))  # Columns are RangeIndex
                                                         # Index is RangeIndex
```

Comment: I get this :AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'. I have added how my df look like.

Comment: @db18 What you call `df` is really a list (probably shouldn't do that, it's very confusing). Rename it to `df_l` and the above will work.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just strip the columns from every dataframe by `df.columns = range(df.shape[1])`, since you don't care about column names.

Comment: @ALollz: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will do it at the beginning adding `skiprows=1`

```
names=[0,1,2,3,4]# what every you want to call them ..

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, usecols = [0,1,2,3,4],skiprows=1,names=[0,1,2,3,4]) for f in files])
```

Comment: What's the first line exactly doing?

Comment: @db18 rename your columns for example you want to call them a ,b ,c ,d ,e , just write name=list('abcde') or even name= ['oof,'boo','soo',too',moo']

Comment: @db18 if you need more explanation just let me know

Comment: But this become unscalable if I have, say, 200 columns. I can't rename them all manually.

Answer (score 0):

Once you put all the data frames into a list, try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
for df in df:
    result = pd.concat([result,df.rename(columns=df1.columns)], ignore_index=True)
```