# Concat two dataframes with different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I concat two dataframes with different columns in pandas, passing the column header also as row into the new dataframe which will have not headers. result_df is the desired format

[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590866/python-pandas-concat-dataframes-with-different-columns-ignoring-column-names) here the column count remains same, which is not what is desired here

```
>df_may

  id  quantity  attr_1  attr_2
0  1        20       0       1
1  2        23       1       1
2  3        19       1       1
3  4        19       0       0

>df_jun

  id2  quantity2  attr_12  
0  5         8       1       
1  6        13       0       
2  7        20       1       
3  8        25       1       

>result_df
0 id  quantity  attr_1  attr_2
1  1        20       0       1
2  2        23       1       1
3  3        19       1       1
4  4        19       0       0
5 id2  quantity2  attr_12  
6  5         8       1       
7  6        13       0       
8  7        20       1       
9  8        25       1
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try?

```
merged = pandas.concat(
    [df_may, df_jun.rename(columns={"id2": "id", "quantity2": "quantity", "attr_12": "attr_1"})],
    ignore_index=True,
)
```